# STS doesn't start after Windows 10 restart

Tags: eclipse, windows-10

my STS will not start, after a hard Windows restart. I see no respons or even a task. My other eclipse neon won't start also. I don't know what i can do? I also tried to "reinstall" the sts.

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

I had to reinstall Java sdk and after that everything Workshop fine.

Greetings

Lukas